# check the value returned by array_rand?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, syntax-error

I'm trying to get some PHP to check if a specific value is pulled out of an array, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. It actually causes the site to go black.

```
<?php

$message_array = file("http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/Subtitles.css");

$message = array_rand($message_array);

echo "$message_array[$message]";

$GfCheck = "<audio id='audio' src='example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/example.wav'; preload='auto' ></audio><a onclick='GFFUNC()'><img src='example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Gf.png'; height='90px' alt='gf' title='gf'/></a>";

if ($message_array[$message] == $GfCheck) { $Gf = "1" } else { }
?>
```

the $Gf would then in turn add a secret section to a menu later on.
Can anyone help me figure out what's going wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `$message` contains the key and not the value of the line, so you probably want to use `if ($message_array[$message] == $GfCheck)`. But remember, that `file()` also includes new lines at the end of the line, so you probably want to pass the flag: `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` as second parameter to `file()`

Comment: Ah, I see! How would I do the latter part of your answer? I know enough PHP to get me through, but I don't know what to do with that part!

edit: that said, what if I put the value at the top of the array, and checked $message against "1"? would that work?

Comment: See the manual of [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), you would just pass it as second parameter to the function, e.g. `$message_array = file("your/path", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php ^^ when working with PHP, that manual will be your best friend for help with functions.

Comment: I'm trying to sort this out, but it seems two parts of the code are causing issues. both the value, and the array.

Comment: the actual value is like: "$GfCheck = "<audio id='audio' src='http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/example.wav' preload='auto' ></audio><a onclick='GFFUNC()'><img src='http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Gf.png' height='90px' alt='gf' title='gf'/></a>";"

Comment: while the code after is "if ($message_array[$message] == $GfCheck) { $Gf = "1"; } else { }". I have added the flag. Do you see issues with any of these values?

Comment: if you're getting a blank screen, it could mean syntax errors. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - what does it have to do with a CSS file though?

Comment: the CSS file is named that, solely as it's easier to edit in Wordpress. it is in reality a plaintext file, with a list of phrases in HTML format.

Comment: Ok, well I've sorted out the black screen. it was to do with the file flag recommendation. It should be noted, I'm using wordpress. I forgot to include that tag. perhaps that conflicted with the suggestion. In any case, it isn't crashing, but it's also not working!

Comment: Almost sorted this, I just need to get the php to echo in the footer of the wordpress site! it seems the code executes well. upon testing <?php if($Gf)  {echo "AAAAAAAAAA"; } ?>, I get a string of A's, so the code is working. now I just need to get it to recognise in the footer segment of my site!

Answer (score 0):

Answer largely came from Rizier123's comments on the main post.

While the file tag did not work, the code did in the end. I am left with an issue of global variables now, but the hard part is done!